# Titanium row data selection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, titanium

I have a text written in Titanium.UI.TableViewRow. Is it possible to to copy the row text on selecting the row as we do in Textfiled or textArea. I inserted a text field in row, but it selects the text only if i focus on the written text not on any part of row.

Answer (score 0):

yes..

if you need to get the title of the row:

```
rowTitle = yourTableView.data[indexOfSection, no Section=0].rows[indexOfRow].title;
```

if you need to get the text of the label/textfield/..

```
text = yourTableView.data[indexOfSection].rows[indexOfRow].children[indexOfChild].text
```

Comment: Will it show the copy option just like text box filed shows on holding the key..?

Comment: you could try something like yourTableView.fireEvent('touchstart'); no idea either this works or if it is the correct event to fire